# SAPUI5 binding JSON model to control

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel

I am an ABAPer and learning `SAPUI5`. I am practising master-detail application through `splitApp` control. I have been searching for this kind of example but did not find any. so, i am writing here. Please guide me if possible.

I am using local JSON model(entries in a file named as Products.json). I have two views *first.xml* and *seconds.xml* which are master and detail respectively.

In first view I have a list and below is the code written in `onItemSelect` event of this list

```
var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource();
var oContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext("products");
var sPath = oContext.getPath();
var oPrdDetails = sap.ui.xmlview("view.second").byId("prdDetails");
oPrdDetails.bindElement({ path: sPath, model: "products" });

var oListDetails = sap.ui.xmlview("view.second").byId("listDetails");
oListDetails.bindElement({ path: sPath, model: "product2" });
```

`Id="prdDetails"` is panel in second view and `Id="listDetails"` is a list in second view. My problem is these controls doesn't get updated using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

SAPUI5 Developer Guide contains the necessary steps in the [Walkthrough tutorial](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef.html). It's recommended to do this by navigation in case of Master-Detail.

In your onItemSelect(), you can navigate to a route using this snippet:

```
var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
oRouter.navTo("detail", {
    invoicePath:     oItem.getBindingContext("invoice").getPath().substr(1)
});
```

In your detail view, you have to subscribe to pattern matched event like this:

```
oRouter.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);
```

The framework will call the specified `this._onObjectMatched` when the proper URL hash is requested:

```
_onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
    this.getView().bindElement({
        path: "/" + oEvent.getParameter("arguments").invoicePath,
        model: "invoice"
    });
}
```

If you bind the element to the UI, you can assign properties to controls in your view relatively ({propName}).

Of course, you have to set up the routing and component.js for your application, but this is also described in the walkthrough.

The example application can be downloaded from [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.32/code) (top right corner, Download button)

Comment: Thanks nistv4n. I have gone through this tutorials earlier. I wanted to do this without routers as I wanted to make it simple.

Comment: first controller
  onItemSelected: function(oEvent) {
   var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource();
   var oContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext("products");
   var sPath = oContext.getPath();

   sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.sPath = sPath;
   sap.ui.controller("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.second").onBeforeRendering();

  }

 onBeforeRendering: function() {
   sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.oPrdDetails.bindElement({
    path: sap.ui.getCore().AppContext.sPath,
    model: "products"
   });

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a Textbox (`<Text text="..." id="sample"/>`) you must use `bindProperty()`

```
var path = oEvent.oSource.oBindingContexts.modelName.sPath;
var item = this.byId("sample");
item.bindProperty("text", `modelName>${path}/Name` );
```

Alternate for oBindingContext was: `oEvent.oSource.getBindingContext("modelName").sPath`

In bindProperty you must add the name of the Property (/Name, /Size, /Price). In this sample I use a template-string with backticks.
Another way:

```
var bindingPath = "modelName>" + path + "/Name"
item.bindProperty("text", bindingPath);
```